# Compatibility of RMI Calls / EJB Calls from Weblogic 14.1.1.0.0 to Weblogic 10.3.6.0

Tags: ejb, weblogic, rmi, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x

I am facing issue when I am trying to call the Remote interface that is deployed on another server.

Initially I was getting `[Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[` error. On searching I found out that I need to enable global trust between these 2 Weblogic servers.

[I used this reference article from Oracle website to enable Global trust](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/EnableGlobalTrustBetweenDomains.html)

After enabling global trust, now I am facing below error.

**Update :-**

> There were multiple jars with the same class that's why I was getting below issue. But somehow Now I am again facing `[Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[` error. Not able to understand what is happening. Could some one please hep me out with this ?

```
        weblogic.utils.NestedException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/org/DataType
        weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.gotExceptionReceiving(RJVMImpl.java:1269)
        weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.gotExceptionReceiving(ConnectionManager.java:1238)
        weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.gotExceptionReceiving(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:629)
        weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.hasException(MuxableSocketT3.java:687)
        weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverExceptionAndCleanup(SocketMuxer.java:860)
        weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverHasException(SocketMuxer.java:794)
        weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:606)
        weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:563)
        weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
        weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
        weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
        weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)

Nested Exception/Error:

weblogic.utils.NestedException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/org/DataType
        weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.gotExceptionReceiving(RJVMImpl.java:1266)
        weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.gotExceptionReceiving(ConnectionManager.java:1238)
        weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.gotExceptionReceiving(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:629)
        weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.hasException(MuxableSocketT3.java:687)
        weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverExceptionAndCleanup(SocketMuxer.java:860)
        weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverHasException(SocketMuxer.java:794)
        weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:606)
        weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:563)
        weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
        weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
        weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
        weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

Not able to understand which configurations are exactly missing ? Could anyone please help me with this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is pretty similar to ClassNotFoundException. Make sure the CLASSPATH of the problematic WLS instance, includes the jar file including the com/org/DataType class.